# Nginx SSL Certificate failed SSL: error:0B080074:x509 (Google Cloud)

Tags: ssl, nginx, google-compute-engine, reverse-proxy, google-cloud-platform

My server was hosted in Bluehost (Apache), the certificate was working fine. Now, I'm using Google Cloud for multiple pages in NodeJS on different port using `proxy_pass`. I am trying to configure the SSL but I have problems. I was looking for similar questions, but it still shows the same error. I created the key file following this [link](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/6487319)

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**:

> 2015/07/08 10:47:20 [emerg] 2950#0: SL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/domain_com/domain_com.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)

When I put on console:

**openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in domain_com.key** shows me this:

```
Modulus=D484DD1......512 characters in total......5A8F3DEF999005F
```

**openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in ssl-bundle.crt**:

```
Modulus=B1E3B0A.......512 characters in total......AFC79424BE139
```

This is my Nginx setup:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_com/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_com/domain_com.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain_com.access.log;

    location / {
       proxy_set_header                         Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
       proxy_pass                               http://localhost:8086;
       proxy_read_timeout                       90;
       proxy_redirect                           http://localhost:8086 https://www.domain.com;
    }
}
```

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem may occur in case of wrong concatenation order. You tried:

```
cat www_example_com.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt  COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > ssl-bundle.crt
```

Which looks correct, but concatenation usually require to eliminate extra download from root CA, therefore Nginx creator [said](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,176163,218475#msg-218475):

> Browsers usually store intermediate certificates which they receive
>   and which are signed by trusted authorities, so actively used browsers
>   may already have the required intermediate certificates and may not
>   complain about a certificate sent without a chained bundle.

[The official docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains) explicitly says:

> If the server certificate and the bundle have been concatenated in
>   the wrong order, nginx will fail to start and will display the error
>   message:
>
> ```
> SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(" ... /www.example.com.key") failed
>    (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:
>     X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
> ```
>
> because nginx has tried to use the private key with the bundle’s first
>   certificate instead of the server certificate.

So to solve the problem please try:

1. Attach *www_example_com.crt* to ssl_certificate Nginx config key
2. Download latest Comodo CA certificates SHA2 from [official web page](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/620/0/which-is-root-which-is-intermediate) and  try one more time to concatenate the bundle

Comment: @wZVanG sure, let's get it sorted today.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, What do you mean by "Attach"?. I am very new on Ubuntu and servers configuration, please verify the question's edit. Excuse my english

Comment: @wZVanG ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/dragonboundaimbot_com/www_example_com.crt;

Comment: Yes, I know, I knew you'd say about the path, but that are there.

Comment: Most likely the error is in the key (I created following the [guide](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/6487319)), if I had not been a mistake directory. What could happen here?

Comment: @wZVanG the key is generated by Comodo in your case, you only generate CSR record

Comment: @wZVanG either of last two in sslcerts directory

Comment: It's works!, last dude please, how to redirect: `http://www.domain.com, https://www.domain.com, http://domain.com` to `https://domain.com`?: I use now: `server {
    listen 80 443;
    server_name dragonboundaimbot.com www.dragonboundaimbot.com;
    return 301 https://dragonboundaimbot.com$request_uri;
}
` but this returns parameter invalid...

Comment: @wZVanG please share the output of *nginx -t*

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "443" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dragonboundaimbot:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: @wZVanG Basically leave your configuration as described originally plus add a 5-line server block for port 80 with return 301.

Comment: Check the edit question's image, also I want redirect `https://www.domain.com` to `https://domain.com`, how to?

Comment: According to [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) *return 301 https ://dragonboundaimbot.com$request_uri; }* within the second block with SSL configuration.